# Manipulating with wsdl response

Tags: java, gwt, wsdl

suppose after running wsdl2java we got response

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "response", propOrder = {
    "responseDate",
    "institutionList"
})
@XmlRootElement(name="response")
public class Response implements Serializable {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar responseDate;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected List<InstitutionList> institutionList;

    public XMLGregorianCalendar getResponseDate() {
        return responseDate;
    }

    public void setResponseDate(XMLGregorianCalendar value) {
        this.responseDate = value;
    }

    public List<InstitutionList> getInstitutionList() {
        if (institutionList == null) {
            institutionList = new ArrayList<InstitutionList>();
        }
        return this.institutionList;
    }

}
```

and `InstitutionList` has deep structure. Because of some imports i can't serialize my `Response` (its needed for GWT), so i have to manually make some `HashMap` (which can be serialized) and fill all fields from deep structure. Is there any way not to do this? Also if i want save data from `Response` in database i have to make something like hashmap with all values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two different ways of doing this (None of them are very comfortable).

GWT Client Code - (RPC) -> Server Code - wsdl2java ->   SOAP web service
Assuming you are not using app engine, there is no restriction whatsover.
This approach duplicates the entity objects in a way. For example, if you have a UpdateUser SOAP web service, wsdl2java will generate one set of classes, and you will need another set of classes for the rpc code.

GWT Client Code - Request Builder + framework -> SOAP Web Service
You can create the necessary SOAP headers in the browser, and then send a request using Request Builder. You would have to write a modified version of wsdl2java to create GWT compatible classes.